# How do you store scoby?

Tags: fermentation, kombucha

[Scoby](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCOBY) for kombucha usually needs to be fed every 10-14 days. I’m going away for a month and can’t take it with me. I need to devise a super simple way my family can take care of it till I get back. What’s the best way to do this? I would assume that feed it right before I leave and put it in the fridge but it is exposed to air and until the PH goes up (due to it being cold and slowed down) I’m concerned it will go moldy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not EVER refrigerate a kombucha scoby, as this will weaken several of the bugs comprising it and make it more susceptible to mold.

You can actually just let it keep going past 10-14 days. The tea will continue to acidify and the scoby will be happy hanging out in it. Just leave it where it won't be disturbed, as always.

Here's an [article](https://www.kombuchakamp.com/scoby-hotel-maintenance)
which talks about maintaining scobys in your "hotel" long-term.